# how to make horizontal scrolling naigation for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to create a navigation similar to one shown here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lodaqh3st2qx1o/2014-07-11_8-56-53.mp4

I actually need to use it as a progress bar, where it jumps to next page as user progresses. But i want them to be able to navigate through pages if needed.

I can not add iframe of overflow-x because it will add a scrollbar. Is there any other possibility or approach?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want vertical scroll, or horizontal scroll like in that video but it's the same thing (actually vertical scroll is simpler). For horizontal something like this:

```
nav {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 40px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```

You basically fix the height of the menu and allow it to `overflow-x`. Then you place the `li`'s side-by-side. The `white-space: nowrap` is also important ensure the list doesn't break on to a new line.

On desktop you will see a scrollbar, but on a mobile phone it will look better.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7mMB/